# formatting strings in list of lists

Tags: python, string

I have this list of list

```
a = [['c', '1.3e-8', '4.5e-8'], ['h', '3.4e-5', '2.3e-7', '2.3e-5']]
```

I want to format the 'e' strings only as

```
a = [[ 'c', '0.000000013', '0.000000045'], ['h', '0.000034', '0.00000023', '0.000023']]
```

How can I do this in Python? Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried until now? Why does the second list in the first line have 4 elements and 3 in the second line?

Comment: Do the sublists always have the same structure (a single letter string, followed by numeric ones)?

Comment: And why does the result for '1.3e-9' evaluate to '0.00000' (5 sig figs), while '4.5e-8' evaluates to '0.00000045' (8 sig figs)?  Can you make your specification more clear please?

Comment: this is just an example. Lists have same number of elements but the first element is not a float looking string where as others are float looking strings. I want to format the 'e' part of strings, but want to keep the first element of the list. I am very new in learning Python. Thanks for your comments and I hope I am able to explain what I intend to do. Best!

Comment: You still haven't addressed several of the problems with your expected output. Again, why does '1.3e-9' -> '0.00000' while '4.5e-8' -> '0.00000045'? Why do both '2.3e-7' and '2.3e-5' -> '0.00023'??

Comment: Two-Bit Alchemist: I have edited the list. I want to play with format of the last three elements of list while doing nothing with the first one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you sure only first element is not a float.

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = [['c', '1.3e-8', '4.5e-8'], ['h', '3.4e-5', '2.3e-7', '2.3e-5']]

for inx, rec in enumerate(a):
    a[inx] = [rec[0]] + ['{:.{precise}f}'.format(Decimal(val),
                precise=int(val[-1])+1) for val in rec[1:]]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[['c', '0.000000013', '0.000000045'], ['h', '0.000034', '0.00000023', '0.000023']]
```

Comment: Your code gives TypeError, "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.